# Android: EditText.getText().toString() not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I use this code to build an AlertDialog with an EditText:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null));
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        mInput = ((EditText) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null).findViewById(R.id.etxtDialog)).getText().toString();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

When I run this code though, the mInput.length() == 0, so the string is empty. The line `mInput = ((EditText) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null).findViewById(R.id.etxtDialog)).getText().toString();` is executed though and the EditText does contain some characters. Why isn't this code working?

Comment: Split this huge term up into one method call per line and look at the results of the single method calls.

Comment: @Merlin Check my answer. Your full n final solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing it wrong... Hold the instance of your inflated view and use it later. For example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Title");
final View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
builder.setView(v);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       mInput = ((EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etxtDialog)).getText().toString();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this way

```
    ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme );
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder( cw );
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cw.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view,null);    

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setView(layout);
    mInput = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.etxtDialog);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           String value =  mInput.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Here: R.style.AlertDialogTheme is your application theme

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating a new view each time you click on the `positiveButton` (`inflate` is called every time). You should do it like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Title");
View v=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
builder.setView(v);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        mInput = ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etxtDialog)).getText().toString();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your full and final solution. This is how i did:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH.mm.ss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    userInput.setText(currentDateandTime);

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                                    {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
                                                        {
                                                            if(userInput.getText()+"" != "")
                                                            {
                                                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AskForTextFile.class);
                                                                i.putExtra("userInput",userInput.getText()+"");
                                                                startActivity(i);
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter backup name to go further.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                        );

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                                        {
                                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
                                                            {
                                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                        );

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this---

Replace this line---

```
  mInput = ((EditText) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null).findViewById(R.id.etxtDialog)).getText().toString();
```

With--

```
mInput = ((EditText) builder.findViewById(R.id.etxtDialog));
String input= mInput.getText().toString();
```